# Porque no me inyecta el valor de las propiedades?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un problema.
Tengo una librería que llama a HttpClient de java.net, y le paso las propiedades a través de el archivo de configuracion application.properties.

Pero no se porque motivo no me las está cogiendo.

La clase en cuestion es la siguiente:

```
package com.projects.beans;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.time.Duration;

@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class Portal {

    private HttpClient httpClient;

    @Value("${portal.timeout}")
    private String timeout;

    @Value("${portal.http_version}")
    private String http_version;

    @Value("${portal.priority}")
    private String priority;

    @Value("${portal.redirect}")
    private String redirect;
    
    public Portal () {
        this.httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Long.parseLong(timeout)))
                .version(HttpClient.Version.valueOf(http_version))
                .priority(Integer.parseInt(priority))
                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.valueOf(redirect))
                .build();
    }

    public String get(URI uri, String[] headers) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        HttpRequest requestBuilder = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(uri)
                .headers(headers)
                .GET()
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(requestBuilder, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        return response.body();
    }

    public String post(URI uri, String[] headers, String body) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        HttpRequest requestBuilder = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(uri)
                .headers(headers)
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(requestBuilder, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        return response.body();
    }

    public String post(URI uri, String[] headers, ObjectNode body) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        HttpRequest requestBuilder = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(uri)
                .headers(headers)
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(String.valueOf(body)))
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(requestBuilder, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        return response.body();
    }
}
```

mi archivo de application.properties es el siguiente:

```
portal.timeout=5
portal.http_version=2
portal.priority=1
portal.redirect=NEVER
```

Esta libreria y esta clase la estoy usando desde otra aplicacion SpringBoot, de esta manera,
Tengo una clase ChatGPT que recibe una clase Portal que es con la clase que voy hacer las peticiones http, esta clase portal utiliza java.net.HttpClient pero quiero que coja las propiedades del archivo de configuración.

```
import com.projects.CheChatGPT.services.ChatGpt;
import com.projects.beans.Portal;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.Scanner;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CheChatGptApplication {
    public static final String EXIT = "EXIT";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ChatGpt chatGpt = new ChatGpt(new Portal());
```

Sabeis que puede pasarle?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto.

Me había cargado sin querer el el run en el main y no levantaba el contexto de Spring.

Vaya toda la tarde para esto.